# Converting a JSON body into a REST URI

Tags: json, rest

can someone please advise how can I convert this JSON body into a REST URI ?

```
GET api/_search
{
 "age":"5",
 "aggs" : {
 "uniq_gender" : {
 "terms" : { "field" : "Gender.keyword" }
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is the resource you are performing a search for? it should be a noun, e.g. customer or employee or smth

Comment: The Gender.keyword

Comment: it is not a recource, it is a filter - search input. What kind of entity is the result of search (output)?

Comment: The output is a nested json body. Example: 

`{
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 30003,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "uniq_gender": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "America",
          "doc_count": 11570
        },
        {
          "key": "AMI",
          "doc_count": 8266
        }`

Comment: and I want to access the `"key"` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may proceed with one of two options:

1. Use `POST` with body

   ```
   POST api/_search
   {
    "age":"5",
    "aggs" : {
    "uniq_gender" : {
    "terms" : { "field" : "Gender.keyword" }
      }
     }
   }
   ```

It may seem like a hack, but it is simple and frankly it is widely used. Basically from `REST` perspective it may be considered as resource creation (`filter` rather than `seach` might be a better word here).

2. Use query string with `GET`.

Something like:

```
GET api/_search?age=5,field=Gender.keyword
```

The problem with using query string is that it may be limited. In RFC there is  [a code for such a case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/414). For example IE browser has such a limit - [see details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812925/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-query-string).

Generally speaking if there is no technical problem, readability issue may appear - it is hard to deal with 1000+ symbols string.